# Gradle project sync fails on new install of Android Studio 0.4.6

Tags: android, android-studio

***can't resolve error. gradle project sync fail,*** Android Studio 0.4.6 download

The following is the set up, PLEASE ask for more info if needed.
I had it working for 3 months until the upgrade 0.5.4 NOW can't resolve this on a reinstall from scratch.

OS windows 7 x64

Gradle build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Gradle build project:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
   }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Wrapper :

1. distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
2. distributionPath=wrapper/dists
3. zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
4. zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
5. distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip

System paths:

1. ANDROID_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk
2. CLASS_PATH .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tool.jar
3. JAVA_HOME C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
4. JDK_HOME C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
5. Path ......     %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Question 1: to resolve the gradle sync fail

Question 2: the SDK manager is missing and not working from this Android studio build "Y/N"

Answer (score 1):

Change this line...!!

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
}
```

for this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
```

and also android studio is now on its version 0.5.4 so I recomed you to get the latest update... because it include a lot of patches... please let me know if this helped you

**EDIT**

on android studio now you should be able to see a little window that is call gradle console... once you try to sync the gradle project you will see a link that says... you need to update the build.gradle or something like that...

[image]

Comment: Gradle 'MyApplication2' project refresh failed:
            Unable to start the daemon process.
            This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
            For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
            Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
            Please read below process output to find out more:
            -----------------------

Comment: Upgrade done as advised to 0.5.4. The problem still the same as above. Please help as I don't know gradle at all and the gradle.org doc is confusing to me. Also tried deleted .gradle to reload from site being through all Q/A's too.

Comment: geekCode The answer is yes to your Question.

Comment: Thank you geekCode for the spotted mistake , I apologise to all for any confusion. Question amended to 0.5.4.

Comment: update to latest SDK via the manager and change version strings in your gradle build configs. 
you can change gradle to v1.11
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip

finally run Tools>Android>Sync Project ...

Comment: That's the problem it don't work "SDK manager can see any SDK manager exe file" should be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk NOT shipped with Downloaded Package

Comment: I highly recomend you to uninstall the AS and download it again it should be included in the installation package!

Comment: My problem now has escalate to a C++ re-distribution install one. Thanks to all for the help and direction provided "NEED to reload windows from scratch" Never had this problem before now Once again thanks to all.